# gridview, order number + 1/- 1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

So I am working on a gridview that uses the order number to order the table.
However, my users are able to ad a row. What i want is something similar to pages that have the arrows next to each row and the user can click up if they want that row to go up. I also want it to change the actual number in the row column. for the one being moved and for the other one being affected. I hope i am being clear enough

[image: sopadmin]

Answer (score 0):

For the arrow controls, I highly recommend the [AJAX Control Toolkit's NumericUpdown control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx).

It should be pretty simple to create a TemplateColumn with the proper controls.

Now the question is one of performance. Generally, each data change will result in a postback, where you can save the new "order" value and requery your grid data. Done and done. Is that good enough?

### EDIT:

I added this code to the gridview:

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrder" runat="server" Width="40px" />
            <cc1:NumericUpDownExtender ID="nudeOrder" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtOrder"
                Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Width="50" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnOrder" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="UpdateOrder" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then, using the GridView_RowCommand method, I can do the actual data write and force an update of the grid.

Comment: thanks the numeric up down control seems to look nice the only thing i dont get how to use it to change a certain column and certain row